# How would someone actively search for titanium ores or other minerals?

Tags: technology, chemistry, mining

I'm working on a story where the main character has to search for titanium (or rather ores containing titanium) in order to repair the hull of a ship. She's on a habitable world that's essentially a vast ocean dotted mostly by small islands. What I'm going for is that the character has the knowhow and specialized equipment to find and mine it. My main question is, what would that equipment be?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please take a moment to check out our [tour] and [help] and learn a little bit about [what this forum is all about](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7859/what-is-the-worlbuilding-site-about).  There are a few issues with this query: first, you don't appear to have done any research. Google exists for a reason, and it's a great resource for any writer when doing basic research like this! Next: we're a specialty forum, as you can see from the links, dedicated to helping you *build your fictional world or setting*. In this question, you aren't...

Comment: ...asking anything about the underlying functionality or systems of your universe. Which leads to problem three: we don't do stories. This isn't a writing club and you seem to be in need of a place where you can knock around some plot ideas, such as "what is available on the ship to move my plot from point A to point B". If you have a specific and focused question about a worldbuilding problem, we're more than happy to help! Otherwise, please understand that this kind of question is not a good fit here.

Comment: "What is would that equipment be ?" for underwater Titanium prospecting seems like a very reasonable question to me.  I don't think it's story based.

Comment: @elemtilas I don't think it is story based. What equipment is used to find titanium is a focused question rather than asking for ideas. There may be an issue that it is asking about the real world (presumably techniques already exist for finding titanium) but there are constraints, it's an ocean and so probably harder to survey/mine.

Comment: My main isue with this question is that searching for titanium ores is a rather "regular" activity, so the question might be better at earthscience or somewhat like that. Not much of a "worldbuilding" issue here.

Comment: @elemtilas Bear in mind that Worldbuilding is often the default place to ask the hard multidisciplinary questions that don't have a perfect fit somewhere else, and that is fine.  "Given an ocean world, how would one who knew what she was doing prospect for and refine titanium, some science fiction may be allowed" is, as far as I've seen, a great fit for the site. The question is too multifaceted to simply google in an hour or two - at least not until there have been a set of thoughtful answers posted here.  Anyway, too much gatekeeping makes the community seem unwelcoming.

Comment: @SJuan76 Agreed.  The only argument I can see for not asking over on ES instead is that the methods are supposed to be futuristic.  But even then, just because whatever method is chosen is advanced doesn't mean it's categorically different than the real method.  The Ancient Egyptians and modern South Africans both mine gold using deep shafts.

Comment: "Other minerals" would be separate questions as they may have drastically different answers.

Comment: @Jedediah -- Actually, no, that's not fine. That's called other SE sites using us as a dumping ground. We do actually have a well stated purpose, and idle curiosity satisfaction isn't one of them. No matter how interesting the questions actually are! Lastly, if the query is "too multifaceted" to google in an hour, it's too broad for SE and would need to be focused.

Comment: @Bellerophon -- The MC has the knowledge and the equipment at hand, according to the author. The question, read as "which equipment should the MC choose" is story based; if we read it "I don't know anything about mining equipment", then it's no longer a question of worldbuilding. Either way is, really, off topic here. There is simply no worldbuilding problem or issue that the OP is having difficulty solving!

Comment: Have you ever tried asking questions of other science-based SEs?  I have.  And they don't want to hear about anything other than what actually exists, often only right here, right now.  How much oxygen do plants need to live, do they generate enough to live on their own (ie: can I plant flora in a solid CO2 atmosphere)?  'There's enough oxygen in the air over any stage in Earth's history, why are you asking this?'  Venus.  'Too hot, they die.'  Cold Venus.  'Whut?'

Comment: @elemtilas By that logic any question on this site could be reworded that way. "My world has giant monsters but I don't know anything about biology to justify them. What do?" And you have this catch-22 where your questions are either Googleable and you're told "use Google" or not and it's "too broad". As user3082 says there are lots of setting-related questions that are arguable "worldbuilding" most of the other SEs won't answer because they're not immediately applicable to the present. The only place that might come close is Writing SE, but they're more focused on plot and writing.

Comment: @user2352714 - That's why queries have to be focussed: not just "what do i do?" but "given constraints 1 through 18, is X plausible?" Just because the sciencey stacks don't want to field speculatively relevant queries doesn't mean they should be dumped here. This community does have a clearly defined purpose, and that purpose isn't to be Biology's or Astronomy's dumping ground; and it isn't to be an all purpose curiosity satisfaction forum. Leave that to Reddit.

Comment: @user3082 -- Yes, I actually have tried asking a query on Biology. I sought an assessment of a focussed and clearly defined phenomenon of wild rodent behaviour. It got closed for being "opinion based". Whatever. That doesn't give me leave to dump my own question here in WB!

Comment: @elemtilas The problem is what is and isn't acceptable *isn't* clearly defined. The Help Center is very vague beyond "this is an SE about worldbuilding" and "no plot/character-driven questions". Most history or culture-based questions here get closed pretty quick because interpretation of history (and how it might apply to another world) tends to be subjective, and many evolution-based questions I have seen not closed are also opinion-based. "How could a single person with futuristic technology find and mine titanium on an ocean world" seems downright objective by comparison.

Comment: @user2352714 - Yep! I don't disagree with that. Vagueness is a thing that has been discussed on Meta in the past, and I'd say needs to be revisited there. Just so you're aware: I consider myself very lenient when it comes to what I find acceptable here. I almost never VTC opinion based queries and tend to let slide many questions that could be closed for lack of focus or detail. That's because I'm really more interested in helping folks with their worldbuilding, a topic inherently contrary to SE's basic nature. When it comes to questions like this one, I just find it much easier to close.

Answer (score 5):

The main thing she is going to need is an understanding of geology so she now what kinds of minerals to look for and where they are likely to occur. Hopefully she has existing geoligic mapping of the planet, this may not tell her where ore is but will drastically narrow down the paces she will look.

fortunately most titanium is mined from just two minerals, ilmenite (FeTiO3) and rutile (TiO2) both of which occur in similar conditions. Both are magmatic products, but are far easier to mine out of sedimentary deposits, where they can be more concentrated. Most often occuring in well sorted placer deposits, usually heavy metal sands which are beach deposits with major volcanic source rock. Rutile is far rarer but also far purer so it is up to you which to use, it does not change the process for your purposes.

It is roughly a six step process I will break down into two parts.

Part 1, First note such mining is a bulk mining process, basically strip mining. You are shifting a lot of sand. So she will need heavy earth moving equipment, some kind of sequential sorter (likely a combination of magnetic and density based), and lastly a simple chemical leeching system. It is not all that different from leech extracting gold up to this point, you can watch any of the many gold miners on TV to get a feel for it, you end up with a titanium rich iron ore.

Part 2. the next step is to smelt out the iron, as a side benefit you get a lot of usable iron this way but it may be less than the total amount of titanium (some deposits can be as high as 60% titanium). Next you chlorinate the slag off the iron, basically a chemical steam bath. lastly you smelt the Titanium tetra-chloride in an arc smelter (no oxygen is essential) to get the metal.  You can get a basic breakdown of the process [here](https://www.britannica.com/technology/titanium-processing/Extraction-and-refining) and a more in depth look at the process [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/275/1/012016/pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Go to where titanium is naturally scavenged in the ocean.**

On earth, there is a lot of titanium in the crust.  But barely any dissolved in seawater.  Why?

[Dissolved titanium in the open ocean](https://www.nature.com/articles/348322a0)

> Dissolved titanium is depleted in surface waters and enriched in deep
>   waters, with a range of more than two orders of magnitude, and there
>   are several indications that it is scavenged (removed by biotic or
>   abiotic processes).

If it is being scavenged from the open water, where is it accumulated?  I think no-one knows for sure.  Other metals collected from the water column accumulate into nodules - probably mostly thru biogenic processes.  Is there titanium in these nodules?  Yes!

[13.11 - Deep-Ocean Ferromanganese Crusts and Nodules](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780080959757011116?via%3Dihub)

[image]

> /Titanium reaches high concentrations of up to nearly 3% in crusts and
>   nodules./

My proposition: rather than adapt terrestrial titanium mining techniques (with which you are unfamiliar), make plausible science fiction.  The authors of the above linked article propose that metallic nodules on the ocean floor could serve as a source for various metals.  On earth we would probably not get titanium this way because it is a lot easier to scrape out of the crust.  But other rarer metals might be worth the trouble.

On your world, there is really no crust to scrape.  Collecting these nodules (which form biogenically) is worth the trouble.  And more fun for a fiction because she can do it by hand, in the depths of an ocean world where there will be exciting hazards.  Perhaps the organisms scavenging the titanium might not want give it up - instead of nodules you can have the titanium present in shells or colonies of creatures.  Maybe she figures that out because one washes up on her beach and she checks the Ti content accidentally and serendipitously.

And she can still use her technical expertise - once she schleps these nodules back upstairs she still has to refine them.  I hope she has some scifi tech for that part because as I understand it is not easy.

Comment: while possible why mine something that might have 3% titanium under the best case scenario vs heavy metal sands which can have as much as 60% titanium ore?

Comment: @John - I had no idea there were sands that were such rich sources of titanium!  I could not turn that info up w (admittedly brief) google.  Link?

Comment: sources are in my answer

Comment: @John Sands require deposits on the surface, and weathering.  How many heavy metal sand deposits are found on our world, on islands?  I'd lay money on none (Madagascar does, but is that the size island we're talking about?).  If there are a ton more islands on this world, you'd have to explain how there are not continents. - (THM) concentrate from the bulk sand, in most ore deposits of this type is around 1% heavy minerals.  Unique South African sands; 86% (continent, plus long weathering/removal of light sand (storms)).

Comment: @user3082 many are on islands, it occurs most commonly in beach sand, more is on continents on earth becasue the majority of beaches are on continents. on a world dominated by continents most of every land feature is on continents. If you are going to change it up and argue averages, what is the average content of titanium in manganese nodules, drastically less than 1%. also if they have islands, they have surface lava deposits.

Comment: @john Only one major Ti producer is on an 'island' (see prior).  Yup, and that's why they're in beach sand: because they have a whole continent to refine from.  No continent == no beach sand full of heavy metals.  Nodules have no bearing on beach sand (and, in predominately oceanic world, may in fact have a higher content, because now most deposits are below water).  Islands come and go, most volcanic islands only last a couple million years, don't have a large size, and thus don't get a chance to refine much (even if they had much - smaller landmass == less source material to work with).

Comment: These sand deposits are rarely continental distance from their source rock, the major metal sand deposits are not in larger delta which require large feeder areas. they are mostly coastal marine deposits from nearby mountain ranges,  not fluvial ones. can they form inland, sure they can form anywhere you have nearby source rock. I can name several island known deposits, Madagascar, Japan, Sri Lanka, New Zealand's north island. Also don't confuse most with all.

Comment: This should end the argument, Hawaii has titanium deposits including soil deposits as high as 30%.  beware this is a direct download link, https://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/bitstream/10125/53872/CtahrpsAgExpRes138.pdf

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I have no actual mining experience.)

If she wants to find it quickly, Star Trek style scanners.  Alternatively, natives/locals who already mine the metal.

Otherwise, I think you are taking mineral samples all over the place and analyzing them, for years, until you find traces and gradients of trace pointing you towards an ore source.  (One might start with river silt...)

Actually, the structure of the islands could make a big difference.  If they are volcanic, volcanic ores are conceivable.  If they are older coral islands, the only way you would get ores is if some life form concentrated the mineral you are looking for.

Underwater mining might or might not be possible.

Also, she does have one known available source:  Her ship's hull.  If she can shave a bit off elsewhere (reducing safety margins...), she might be able to put together enough for repairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of room for world building in this question and a chance to have the protagonist to interact with several different disciplines and communities to develop the technology to fix the ship.

Titanium is a light strong metal, but not the only metal around and finding substitutes and workarounds as well as helping natives build a technology base could be an interesting aspect of the world building.

As mentioned in previous answer, the geology becomes an interesting aspect of the background of the story, but in addition to paying attention to some of the minerals that contain titanium, the geology of islands and sea level changes, are they volcanic, or remnants of sedimentary rock that has been upthrusts, do they contain fossils, or perhaps remnants of ancient civilizations so old that their metals were folded into the rock but could be mined. (I may be getting off topic...)

With respect to undersea mining, there has been interest at various time in scooping up nodules of metal off the seafloor, as well as finding other materials such as methyl hydrates (under relatively cold and high pressure conditions hydrocarbons can freeze into a kind of ice that if you bring to the surface and ignite and burn). I think the nodules were mostly light metals like magnesium and manganese, but could be useful in alloys.

Also there are interesting challenges in exploring undersea and depending on the water depth could play a major role in your world building, in a shallow world where the sunlight penetrates to the bottom (by 400 ft it is almost completely dark) it would be a quite different than a world where it is deep, dark and cold. In the shallow world, you probably would have life adapt quite differently. Humans for instance might have a lot more motivation to free-dive or adapt to pressure changes if the water was only 100 or 200 ft deep and adapt to farming the sea in a very different way than we would. That could include mining resources. Developing tech to mine underwater could go a lot of different ways. Autonomous vehicles if high tech. Or modifying spaceship tech to work with low tech to develop a low tech type mining submarine. Developing or finding crafts people to build out that kind of tech could be interesting and provide plot points where tech or people fail, or have to innovate.

Specifically with Titanium, it is an interesting metal to work. Titanium oxidize so fast and is so reactive that to weld it you need to do it in an inert atmosphere. The rumors are that when the Soviets were developing their titanium hull submarines that had to construct huge warehouse size building  and filled them with Argon to keep the oxygen out, and the workers had to go in essentially space suits to shape and weld the materials.

Another interesting thing with titanium is that when it oxides that the refractive index of the titanium dioxide is large and the thin layers (like an oil film on water) trap the light and the interference results in interesting shimmering colors. So there are jewelry makers who do this initially by anodizing titanium. Aluminium is also reactive and does a similar thing, but is not as reactive as titanium. For both metals the reaction is so fast and self limiting so the metal doesn't "rust" like iron.

Comment: This is more a comment on the question and potential of the setting than an answer.

Comment: fair enough, first time posting, still figuring out the rules